# Embedding Video in O365 Site

Tags: html, embed, office365

I have a video that I would like to embed in an O365 website using HTML5 embeding code.  When I insert it, the video works fine but as soon as I click save the video area is just a black box and I can't play it.  If I click to open it in another window it does play fine though for some reason.

The code I am using is the following:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="my video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my questions remains valid as I don't know why it is happening, I found a work around for anyone having the same issue.

Rather than inserting the html embed code I inserted a media web part which was much easier and worked!  I recommend this route!